# SharePoint 2013 Jslink : Two List having there own jslink not working on same page

Tags: jslink

**Scenario**: We need to display two different list(custom list) on single page.
Both list-view have separate Jslink.

**Issue**: Let say listview1 and listview2. If i add listview1 and then listview2. Jslink associated with listview2 is called and not the other one and vice-verse.

any pointer will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem people run into because both lists, since they are both custom lists, have `ListTemplateType: 100` and `BaseViewID: 1`.

The workaround for this problem, as described in [this blog post](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/listview-web-part-issues-with-jslink-and-display-templates-a-solution/), is to target your CSR code to different `BaseViewID`s, and then (through Javascript) quickly change the `BaseViewID` of the List View Web Parts just before they are rendered to match what you have specified in your script.

Please see [my answer to this other question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158493/8992) for some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First Add both the List View on page then edit one by one and make sure that you have given right URL of JSLink file in Miscellaneous section of WebPart properties by editing WebPart as show in below:

[image]

Comment: Jslink url are proper, If i add them individually , both are working fine. If added together on same page issue happen as mentioned in my issue section